# How to connect db2 database to ASP.NET Core using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, c#-4.0, db2

I want to create an application to get the value from a db2 database. I am using Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2017 with .NET Core2.1 version.

I have followed many tutorials to configure db2 with Visual Studio 2017, but did not succeed.

Tutorials like:

1. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/96960515-2ea1-4391-8170-b0515d08e4da/entry/Creating_Entity_Data_Model_using_IBM_Data_Server_providers_for_Entity_Framework_Core?lang=en
2. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/96960515-2ea1-4391-8170-b0515d08e4da/entry/DB2DotnetCore?lang=en
3. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/96960515-2ea1-4391-8170-b0515d08e4da/entry/IBM_DB_NET_Provider_for_MS_NET_Core?lang=en

Could you please let me know the step by step what exactly I have to do for db2 connection?

TIA

Comment: Please avoid adding links to questions as part of the question, links tend to become broken over time. Because it's necessary to browse three links to understand your question you're less likely to get an answer.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is “ but did not succeed”? Is DB-first or code-first ?Please show some code you tried or error message .

Answer (score 0):

You should look at dapper.

https://dapper-tutorial.net/dapper

Dapper is installed through NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper

```
PM> Install-Package Dapper
```

Then just use it Like:

```
string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM yourTable;";
string yourConnectionString = "Server=myAddress:myPortNumber;Database=myDataBase;UID=myUsername;PWD=myPassword"

using (var connection = new DB2Connection(yourConnectionString)
{
    var yourQueryFromDBList = connection.Query(sqlQuery).ToList();
    foreach(var item in yourQueryFromDBList)
    {     
        Console.Writeline(item.toString());
    }
 }
```

To find your connection string you can have a look at
[https://www.connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)